# BuddyPress show post author avatar

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

On my home page where all my blog posts are I want to show the avatar of the author and then link it to the members profile so for example: domain.com/members/cameron.

I have managed to get the avatar showing, just need to grab the url: `<a title="View profile for <?php echo get_the_author(); ?>" href=""><?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta('user_email'), $size = '32' ); ?></a>` Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
<a title="View profile for <?php echo get_the_author(); ?>"
   href="/members/<?php echo get_the_author_meta('nickname') ?>">
   <?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta('user_email'), $size = '32' ); ?>
</a>
```

Comment: nickname isn't the same as username though. trying user_login does work but it relies on the URL being /members/ which isn't perfect, but works :/ Thanks